# Cannot display AdMob banners, Received error HTTP response code: 400 etc

Tags: android, admob

Whatever I do I cannot display the banners from Admob, I tested on two Android different devices and here is what I get:

**First device:**

```
I/Ads     ( 8161): Starting ad request.
I/Ads     ( 8161): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
I/Ads     ( 1006): CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
W/Ads     ( 1006): JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=0&request_id=............
W/Ads     ( 1006):  (null:1)
W/Web Console( 1006): The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=0&request_id=............
W/Ads     ( 1006): JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=0&request_id=............
W/Ads     ( 1006):  (null:1)
W/Web Console( 1006): The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=0&request_id=............
W/Ads     ( 1006): JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
W/Ads     ( 1006):  (null:1)
W/Ads     ( 1006): Received error HTTP response code: 400
W/Ads     ( 8161): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads     ( 8161): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Note: here neither onAdLoaded( ) nor onAdFailedToLoad( ) is getting called

**Second device:**

```
I/Ads     ( 1165): CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
I/Ads     ( 1165): Starting ad request.
I/Ads     ( 1165): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.     
I/Ads     ( 1165): CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
W/Ads     ( 1165): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
I/Ads     ( 1165): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
W/Ads     ( 1165): Failed to load ad: 2
```

**My code:**

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle icicle )
{
 super.onCreate( icicle );

m_glView = initOpenGLView( ); 

 m_adMobView = new AdView( this );
 m_adMobView.setAdSize( AdSize.SMART_BANNER );
 m_adMobView.setAdUnitId( "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" );      <----I just replaced the ID with XXX for this example
 m_adMobView.setAdListener( new AdListener( )
  {
   public void onAdLoaded( ) 
   { 
    egNative.LogMessage( "ADMob::onAdLoaded" );
   };
   public void onAdFailedToLoad( )
   {
    egNative.LogMessage( "ADMob::onAdFailedToLoad" );
   }
  }  );

 FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout( getApplicationContext( ) );
 layout.addView( m_glView );

 int gravity = android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | android.view.Gravity.TOP;
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , 
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,  gravity );
  layout.addView( m_adMobView , params );
setContentView( layout );
}

@Override protected void onStart( )
 {
  super.onStart( );
  AdRequest.Builder ad_builder = new AdRequest.Builder( );
  m_adMobView.loadAd( ad_builder.build( ) );
 }
```

I am running the latest version of Google Play services. Also have double checked the Ad unit IDs and they're fine. Not getting any positive results with test Ad unit IDs too. 
Can you guys post any hints eventually?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ensure if you have allowed smart banner from admob account

Comment: Yes, smart banners are enabled. 
I also have tried testing using different WIFI and 3G networks with no different results though.

Comment: You must be testing this on emulator ... Please Add AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

Comment: It has been tested already, but it is the same. I checked many other posts with similar errors and tried some suggested resolutions but I have no change at my side.
For my post here I just replaced the ID with XXXXX so it is not visible, if you were wondering what is XXXX in AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

Comment: Latest version of PlayServices == ?what? Be specific

Comment: Do you have a connection to the net? Ie is your wifi on?

Comment: Do you happen to have any ad blocker or custom rom installed on these devices?

Comment: @William Revision 23, google_play_services_version=7095000

Comment: @William Yes, I have connection to the net. WIFI is on. In fact I tried different WIFIs and 3g networks, same result.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag It's a stock os, just flashed actually. There is a symantec mobile antivirus shipped with the device, which I cannot disable (yay!), but another app run ads fine on the same device. In fact, if I look at the log on the other app, all "**Displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png**" messages are there as well, just the HTTP400 error is missing.

Comment: For a 3rd day I cannot make it work, I even created a brand new project which contains nothing but the admob banner code and I get exactly the same error message.
W/Ads     ( 1006): JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
W/Ads     ( 1006):  (null:1)
W/Ads     ( 1006): Received error HTTP response code: 400
W/Ads     (23331): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads     (23331): Failed to load ad: 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package is blocked by Google AdMob. 
If you received a email like this:

> Hello,
>
> This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not
>   currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a
>   result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.
>
> Issue ID#: 33943***
>
> Ad serving has been disabled to: **APPNAME**
>   (com.example.pack)
>
> Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your
>   account for compliance.
>
> Current account status: Active
>
> Violation explanation
>
> GOOGLE PLAY REMOVAL: AdMob publishers are not permitted to abuse or
>   promote the abuse of any Google product, such as Google Play, YouTube,
>   or Blogger. This includes circumventing, or providing the means to
>   circumvent, the policies or terms of these or other Google products,
>   such as by allowing users to download YouTube videos.
>
> If your app is removed by Google Play policy enforcement, please
>   contact Google Play about an app removal here. If Google Play
>   reinstates your app, please submit an appeal to our team.
>
> Action required: Check account for compliance
>
> While ad serving has been disabled to the above app, your AdMob
>   account remains active. We suggest that you take the time to review
>   the rest of your applications to ensure that they’re in compliance
>   with our policies, and to monitor your apps accordingly to reduce the
>   likelihood of future policy emails from us. Additionally, please note
>   that our team reserves the right to disable accounts at any time if we
>   continue to see violations occurring.
>
> Appeals
>
> If you wish to appeal this disabling then you can do so by using our
>   appeal form.
>
> Thank you for your cooperation.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Google AdMob Team

So now you need to change your package of your app. on eclipse it is  `package="com.example"` in AndroidManifest.xml file

or

on AndroidStudio `applicationId "com.example"` in build.gradle file

Comment: i have same  problem but today solve it thanks for good answere

Comment: is changing the package name the only way?

Comment: @Alexis 
 
yes, because by this package name google blocked you

Comment: @NickUnuchek Hi, Thank you very much for answer, however, I wondering is it possible to contact the Admob to resolve this problem? I have the same issue but not receive such an email though. From the developer site of the Admob, there is nothing unusual, the test Ads show up, but on the real device constantly receive HTTP403, weird..

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue. It started work for me after I had updated my Billing and Payments details in AdMob Account.

Comment: I spent 1 day because of this, then i test with admob app id and test id. I found that i was doing right but problem was with admob account Billing and Payments

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have copied the latest **google-services.json** from firebase console to your project root directory.
2. For native ads, **DON'T** simply copy past the example code given in [Native Ads Express guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express). Analyse the ad space available in your all device supporting screens. Ex., if you have only 300 dp ad space that actually an ad can accommodate, then you should not request the ad size more than 300dp in **adSize** attribute.
   [image: native ad sizes]
3. Check for your device's ad space available(also check for padding and margin) then compare the ad size table above and choose the right value that suites. ex., if your device has 300dp width then change adSize value as **300x150** to get ads and also adjust these values for better ad presentation.
4. If your ad space falls in **medium** category, then create a right ad unit in admob. You can review the ad presentation in admob preview pane with the space you allotted in your code.
5. If you created the AdUnit id newly in Admob, the admob server is taking bit time to review & approve your native ads template. So wait for some time and try again (approx 1-2 hrs). Meanwhile make sure that your code complies with all the above 4 points.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled the google play services update and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from Google Play Services Ads to Firebase Ads and cleaning the project after restarting Android Studio worked for me.