# cant show Ad banner with Google Play Store is missing and Received error HTTP response code: 400

Tags: android, admob

I follow the guide provided by google to try to add a ad banner in my app. 
[Google Mobile Ads SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=zh-CN#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk)

With test app id, it passed and worked. But when changing to my own app id, the ad banner can't be launched and some errors showed in runner console:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>                             Google Play Store is missing.
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
>                             Google Play Store is missing.
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>
> I/Ads: Starting ad request.
>          Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("AA03ACCABC30119875FF8F15346EA795") to get test ads on this device.
>
> W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>
> W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
>
> ```
>    The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
> ```

and

> W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 400
>
> W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>
> W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

I try several ways mentioned on [Cannot display AdMob banners, Received error HTTP response code: 400 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208539/cannot-display-admob-banners-received-error-http-response-code-400-etc)

but it doesn't work.

### Anybody could help with this problem? Thanks a lot in advance.

one update:
I notice one thing that `AdRequest.Builder().build()` in code is automatically  changed to `AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("AA03ACCABC30119875FF8F15346EA795")` to get test ads on this device" in run log. I suspect that I use this phone to test the app, which cause the ad is still in test mode. I will try to download app from app store and check again.

latest update:
After add payment info in admob, the ad bar could work with ad content showing.

Comment: post your code please add this line your app gradle implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1 and add google-services.json file in your project

Comment: Thanks, Kishan. But these two you mentioned are not included in google guide. Does it mean something wrong on that guide?

Comment: check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Currently, I try with Admob only. I am not sure whether firebase is a mandatory now. And I still am confused on different result for test id and mine owe id.

Comment: First of check ad-mob test id work or not